# Ошибка при передаче QStringListModel из cpp в qml

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

Пытаюсь вывести загруженные из папки изображения по сетке в Qt Widget через QListView. Загружаю изображения в c++, отображаю через qml

```
void MainWindow::on_load_triggered()
{
    QStringList Names = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, "Выбор изображений", "C:/");

    NameFolder.setStringList(Names);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("display.qml"));
    view->show();  
}
```

В qml отображаю по сетке, пишу туда свою полученную QStringListModel

```
GridView {
    width: 300; height: 200

   model: NameFolder {}
    delegate: Column {
        Image { source: portrait; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
        Text { text: name; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
    }
}
```

На это выдается ошибка на неизвестный элемент NameFolder. Пыталась использовать Q_PROPERTY - не работает, потому что это модель. Заголовочный файл выглядит так:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QStringListModel NameFolder;


private slots:
    void on_load_triggered();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

Перепробовала несколько способов передачи между слоями c++ и qml, но с моделью ничего не работает как надо. Может кто знает как можно это сделать, желательно попроще?

Comment: Надо скобки `{}` убрать `model: NameFolder`

Comment: не вижу выставление модели в контекст

Comment: может лучше не использовать си++ вообще в этом месте? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmltypes.html#f

Answer (score 0):

Из документации qt

```
class Animal
{
public:
   Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size);
   ...
};

class AnimalModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   enum AnimalRoles {
       TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
       SizeRole
   };

   AnimalModel(QObject *parent = 0);
   ...
};

QHash<int, QByteArray> AnimalModel::roleNames() const {
   QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
   roles[TypeRole] = "type";
   roles[SizeRole] = "size";
   return roles;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   AnimalModel model;
   model.addAnimal(Animal("Wolf", "Medium"));
   model.addAnimal(Animal("Polar bear", "Large"));
   model.addAnimal(Animal("Quoll", "Small"));

   QQuickView view;
   view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
   view.setInitialProperties({{"model", QVariant::fromValue(&model)}});
   ...
}
```

qml:

```
ListView {
   width: 200; height: 250

   required model

   delegate: Text {
       required property string type
       required property string size

       text: "Animal: " + type + ", " + size
   }
}
```